# django ajax multiple form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, forms

My template looks like :

```
    {% for comment in service.comments.all %}
    {{comment.comment}} -- commented by {{comment.user}}<br/>

  <div id="comment-reply">
        `{% for reply in comment.comment_replies.all %}`

    <p>{{reply.comment_reply}} -- replied by {{reply.user}}</p><br/>

    {% endfor %}
  </div>


    <a class="myClick" href="#">Reply</a><br/>
    <form class="comment-replyform" action="some_url" method="post" style="display: none;">{% csrf_token %}

      {{ comment_reply_form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reply">
    </form>

    {% empty %}
    No comments 
    {% endfor %}
```

Here I have comment replies for comment.
    My comments and comment replies are listing properly.
    Here What I want is when I click on `Click` I want to display the comment reply form, which is displaying fine..

My jquery looks like :

```
    $(".myClick").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".comment-replyform").show();
  $(".myClick").hide();
 })

    $('.comment-replyform').on('submit', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
               url: $(this).attr('action'),
               type: $(this).attr('method'),
               data: $(this).serialize(),
               success: function(response) {
                    $('#id_comment_reply').val('');
                    $('#comment-reply').append("<p>"+response.comment_reply+" -- "+"replied by "+ response.user+"</p><br/>")
                }

                });        
    })
```

The problem is when I click on `Click`, it displays all the form for comment replies but I want only the form to be shown where I click

Another thing is when I submit the first form it works well but when I submit second or third form... The value is shown on the first div. I mean the comment reply for second form is appended to first.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is showing all of them because you ask all the elements with the class "comment-replyform" to be shown, instead you have to focus on the one inside the clicked element. 
to do so, replace:

```
 $(".comment-replyform").show();
```

by:

```
$(this).next().next(".comment-replyform").show();;
```

for the second part of your question, it is because you should only have one element with a specific ID, so:

1. replace `id="comment-reply"` with `class="comment-reply"` in your for loop
2. replace  `$('#comment-reply').append(...)` with  `$(this).prev('.comment-reply').append(...)`
3. finally replace `$('#id_comment_reply').val('');` with `$(this).prev('.comment-reply').val('');` and it should work

Comment: when I do $(this).children(".comment-replyform").show(); nothing is shown

Comment: sorry it was no a children in that point, this one should do the trick : `$(this).nextAll(".comment-replyform").show();`

Comment: I did this too.. when I click the  first Click it displays both form and when I click second Click it displays only second form but the Click in form is not shown. Any help ?

Comment: $(this).next().next().show(); this one should work for sure if your html code is exactly the one you provide ( first next is the <br/> second is the one you need)

Comment: I should not provide .comment-replyform" in here ??

Comment: you can but not necessarily because it is just descending the dom and taking the second element after $(this) which is your ".comment-replyform" element

Comment: Its working.. thank you.. just one issue.. when I click on Reply on the first form.. The Reply on the second is hidden. What i want is when I click on the Reply on first it should show the reply form but it should also show Reply on all other

Comment: replace `$(".myClick").hide();` with  `$(this).hide();` , is that what you want ?

Comment: I have replace $('#comment-reply').append(...) with $(this).prev('.comment-reply').append("<p>"+response.comment_reply+" -- "+"replied by "+ response.user+"</p><br/>") and $('#id_comment_reply').val(''); with $(this).prev('.comment-reply').val(''); but my comments are not appending and values are not being cleared

Comment: of so the idea would be to encapsulate each group of '.comment-reply' + '.myclick'  + '.comment-reply for in divs with a class you can call 'finder' and replace `$(this).prev('.comment-reply')` with `$(this).closest('.finder').find('.comment-reply');`